# how to auto popluation of lookup field in vfpage

Tags: visualforce

I have two custom objects A and B contains same lookup field in both objects when i select lookup field object A it Should populate selected value in object B when i select Object B in the related list of objectA.

Comment: Sravanthi, this question got flagged as unclear. Please consider that when asking a question, it's good practise to read it and see how understandable it is to someone unfamiliar to what you're trying to do.  Giving more context and a structured explanation will greatly improve your question. Adding what you've already tried or are uncertain about will prevent answers which are of no help. Both of these tips can greatly improve the answers you receive and the way in which you are helped.  At any time you can still update(edit) your question to improve it or include more info.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Sravanthi,

```
            Please follow this link , its same requirements as what you are looking for.
```

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/05/how-to-auto-populate-lookup-field.html

Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat

Comment: Thanks mr.Pritam Shekhawat i have tried in same format the lookup field is not updating

Comment: could you please share your code here i will look out in code